# Which distance will the rocket fall at?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, velocity, displacement

The first rocket in the world had a mass of 2 kg (without the charge). When the charge bursted, 200 g of explosive gases were thrown out at the speed of 600 meters per second.

Which distance will the rocket fall at after it is launched at an angle of 45° to the horizon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an answer to this question, you must assume that the gasses were expelled all at once by an explosion. Then use conservation of momentum to get the recoil velocity of the (empty) rocket.  With that, use a projectile equation to get the range.  In a real rocket, the burning occurs slowly. That would complicate the problem, since the rocket would be moving under the action of two forces; gravity and thrust.

Comment: Thank you very much!